# GoogleAnalytics Android sample app doesn't work

Tags: android, google-analytics

Good day for all! Please help me with Google Analytics for Android. All day spent for it. I download sample app for Android from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

I simply change PROPERTY_ID for my  "UA-50474843-4" and cannot see any statistics. 
In this app in the Main Activity I add a string: `MyApp.analytics().reportActivityStart(this);` that's must to show some statistics in Google Analytics Overview.

Here is this "Hello world" app: https://yadi.sk/d/BinLKTjah5dbj

Can you open this simple project, change `PROPERTY_ID` for another, check and tell me, what's wrong? I have absolutely no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that even the demo app doesn't work the first 24h, according to http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/google-analytics-common-problems-and-fixes/ but this is not mentioned on the main page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

(but I guess you must have found out by now?)